# DNS settings different between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: mojave, google-chrome, dns

I have an odd issue that I hope someone can help on. I recently switched hosting providers for a subdomain on our website (the main domain is still at the old host). The DNS settings for this subdomain are set with a custom A record which points to the new server's IP address.

I have done a DNS lookup and the A record for this subdomain lists the correct IP.

In Firefox, the subdomain resolves correctly to the new host. However, in both Chrome (and Safari), the subdomain still goes to the old host.

I did a local OS level DNS flush (using `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`) but that seems to not have done anything. Clearing Chrome's cache does nothing. I even tried clearing Chrome's DNS cache. Again, no luck. I am on Mojave.

Comment: Look for a setting where Chrome is using DNS over HTTPS. I’ve found a few google apps where they conveniently add their DNS servers regardless of what you specify.

Comment: @Allan Thanks. I turned that off but unfortunately it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

They use different DNS servers. A similar question was asked on the 'Super User' site of Stack Exchange. The answer explains why there is a difference and how to handle the DNS settings. [The question can be found here](https://superuser.com/questions/65382/does-chrome-use-a-different-dns-server-from-firefox-and-ie-which-use-the-os-defa).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately the most recent content from that post is from 2015 and Chrome no longer has the settings it mentions that I can find.

Comment: If you read it carefully, it doesn't actually use a different server. It just looks up DNS at different times. This could potentially cause differences if you change the DNS in the middle of a Chrome session, but it shouldn't cause a permanent change.